# An Orientation for Measurable Sets

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

It is known that if $M$ is an oriented submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $\omega$ is a compactly supported form on $M$, then
\begin{align}
\int_{M} \omega = - \int_{-M} \omega,
\end{align}
where $-M$ denotes $M$ with opposite orientation. Is there an analogous identity for the Lebesgue integral of Lebesgue integrable functions? That is, can one define *orientation* for arbitrary Lebesgue-measurable sets and their corresponding measures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can of course use the above equation to define an oriented version of the Lebesgue integral, whenever you can define a notion of orientation of the underlying measure space, which is clearly the case for orientable (sub-)manifolds. On the other hand not every measure space admits a meaningful notion of orientation, so the general answer to your question should be no.

Comment: Thanks for the post. I ask the question for this very reason. _Is there a different way to meaningfully define orientation on measure spaces_?

Comment: You actually don't want to define orientation of the measure space itself. Orientation is defined in terms of some other structure of the measure space, for example a vector space structure, or more generally a manifold structure.